# Frontend and backend can't communicate in kubernetes | Nginx and PHP-FPM

Tags: php, docker, vue.js, kubernetes, nginx

I'm porting an application based in Vue.js and php for back that is running in docker-compose. I'm trying to bring it to kubernetes. I did the basic, created the yamls for deployment and services, and put this is in an AKS service. I can reach the front, but the connections between the microservices are broken. I tried many things already but I'm stucked on that.

Frontend has a env that indicates the backend URL. In compose, the value is 'http://localhost:8001/api' and works well. When I deployed to K8s I tried with localhost, backend(kube dns name for backend service that I created), even an LoadBalancer external IP that I created for backend, but nothing works. Backend and frontend docker images has nginx.conf and backend also has php-fpm.conf configured, and seems to be ok.

Here is my frontend and backend yaml files. First I tried using backend as clusterIP and use the kubedns, but this above is the LoadBalancer service. The images are in dockerhub also.

frontend-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: C:\kompose\kompose.exe convert
    kompose.version: 1.26.0 (40646f47)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: frontend
  name: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: frontend
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: C:\kompose\kompose.exe convert
        kompose.version: 1.26.0 (40646f47)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL
              value: http://<IP from loadbalancer svc>:8001/api
          image: jvfazolo/algochallenger-frontend
          name: frontend
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

frontend-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: C:\kompose\kompose.exe convert
    kompose.version: 1.26.0 (40646f47)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: frontend
  name: frontend
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 80
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: frontend
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

backend-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: C:\kompose\kompose.exe convert
    kompose.version: 1.26.0 (40646f47)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: backend
  name: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: backend
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: C:\kompose\kompose.exe convert
        kompose.version: 1.26.0 (40646f47)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: APP_DEBUG
              value: "true"
            - name: APP_ENV
              value: local
            - name: APP_NAME
              value: Boca
            - name: APP_URL
              value: http://<LB SVC IP Backend>
            - name: DB_CONNECTION
              value: pgsql
            - name: DB_DATABASE
              value: boca
            - name: DB_HOST
              value: db
            - name: DB_PASSWORD
              value: boca
            - name: DB_PORT
              value: "5432"
            - name: DB_USERNAME
              value: boca
            - name: LOG_CHANNEL
              value: daily
          image: jvfazolo/algochallenger-backend
          name: backend
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

backend-servicelb.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: C:\kompose\kompose.exe convert
    kompose.version: 1.26.0 (40646f47)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: backend
  name: backend
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 8001
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: backend
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: The browser is intrinsically running outside the cluster, and you'll need to set up some sort of ingress for it to be able to reach the back-end services.  `localhost` will mean the same system running the browser, and the Service names are similarly unreachable from outside the cluster.  If you have a working LoadBalancer Service, that should work; can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: my last try was with LoadBalancer service for backend. The deploy succeeds but I'm not able to reach anything from a browser call.

Comment: I think I got into a more detailed error now. I runned my app in local docker again and tested all my endpoints/paths/subpaths. Frontend paths works well but backend don't and I get errors 401(unauthorized) and 500(internal server error). I see maybe I have to introduce a JWT because app is deployed with authentication.